# Circuit to limit a variable-voltage DC supply to 30V

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, battery-charging, solar-energy

I want to charge a [powerbank](https://manuals.plus/anker/757-series-7-portable-power-station-manual#related_manuals_resources) which supports 11-30V input with a [solar panel](https://manuals.plus/m/515575673f6a3fe12f9e91971bd4cb09ebb055c4c6116c5a1bdb0b5d4e0ad7ed_optim.pdf) with an open-circuit max voltage of 48V (41V under load).

I live in a cloudy area, so I don't expect the solar panel to produce more than 30V under normal conditions.

However, I'd like to build a circuit to protect the power bank from surges > 30V should the sun decide to shine.

This is such an unlikely occurrence that I'm not worried about capturing the energy, so it's fine if the circuit dissipates the overvoltage as heat.

The ideal solution would pass through the source voltage to the output as long as the source voltage is ≤ 30V. When the source voltage is > 30V the ideal solution would express exactly 30V on the output.

An acceptable solution may drop the output voltage to 0V when the input voltage is > 30V.

It's fine for the output voltage to drop below 30V; I expect this to be the primary operating mode of the circuit.

Any solution must be able to handle 11A of current at the source.

I can imagine some convoluted solutions with opamps, but this feels like a common enough situation that there might be a premade solution/pattern to do this.

Comment: This is a rather typical situation. Have you searched for MPPT controllers? https://cleanenergysummit.org/best-mppt-solar-charge-controllers/

Comment: @PStechPaul there might be one inside the "powerbank" already, but it only goes up to 30V input.

Comment: Perhaps it would be possible to rewire the solar panel for 24V rather than 48V? Otherwise, a 24 or 28 volt buck converter should work. It would just run a t 100% PWM up to its rated output voltage, and then would hold output there while adjusting the PWM. I don't know if such 400W switching supplies are available, but should not be hard to design. [edit] I found one that has a maximum output of 8A, for about $30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest, cheapest solution may be a bunch of Zener diodes in parallel, mounted on a PCB with a lot of copper to dissipate the heat.

One cheap way of assembling it would be to get a double-sided copper-clad PC board, with no holes. Then solder the Zener diodes on the edge of the board, with leads going to the copper on the opposite sides of the board. That way, the board will act as a heat sink.

Since you have a 400W panel, any dissipative solution will have to dissipate 100W or more. It doesn't matter how it's done - any shunt regulator will have to do that.

Now, 100W is not little, so to make this feasible you'll want a large piece of copper-clad laminate, or several connected in parallel.

You can use 1N5362BG Zener diodes, rated at 28V, 5W. The output voltage will be a bit higher in practice. With the cheap heat sink solution, you need to derate them at least a bit. Say, 4W. So you'll get 25 or 30 of the diodes. That should do it. If they get super hot - above 100C on the surface - just add another board with same number of diodes, and parallel it.

If you want to adjust the clamp voltage, you can put a bunch of silicon diodes on another smaller board, acting as voltage droppers.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv2yFL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Edge view of a diode soldered across a double-sided copper clad laminate board]
[image: Board-side view of a diode soldered across a double-sided copper clad laminate board]

Comment: I'm not sure these kinds of diodes are suitable to dissipate so much power. Yeah, you could put 100 in parallel on a big heatsink, but one does imagine it can be done without soldering 100 separate components.

Comment: Quick Google suggests that some transistors can dissipate 50W or more (with a really big heatsink) and then you'd only need 2 of them (or 4-5 to have a healthy safety margin) as opposed to 100 individual 1W diodes.

Comment: The Zener diodes I mentioned can dissipate 4W no problem. They are rated at 5W. The problem is really with heatsinking, and a large copper clad board is cheap and easy to deal with, and perfect for a distributed source of heat like a bunch of Zener diodes.

Comment: You will have to dissapate waaay more that 100W, I would assume at LEAST 300W. Solar panel is rated to produce 9.8A at 41V at MPP and aldo will supply a bit more current (10-10,5A, not quite 11A that is SCC -  short circuit current) at 30V compared to 41V. MINIMUM required power to dissipate is 10A*30V=300W. Actual power might be less than that, but board of Zeners must be capable of dissipating 300W in case full battery with full sun.